# Missing Completed event handler on ShareMediaTask

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8

There seems to be no `Completed` event handler for `ShareMediaTask` in Windows Phone 8. Are there any other ways to find out the user has finished? Especially whether it was "successful" would be interesting, because I want to react on this (e.g. give the user soft currency points for sharing an image).

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to know if the user really did the sharing.

Comment: What about detecting completion (or cancelling)? The only thing coming to my mind is to detect activation and deactivation, but that won't be bulletproof.

Comment: nothing in the API .. so yeah, some fkag, detecting deactivation and activation but you still do not not if the user canceled it